# Is transaction confidentiality achievable in Ethereum currently

Tags: transactions, ethereum-classic

I have read about zk-SNARKs on different articles which is written in 2016. So I am wondering if the zk-SNARKs is implemented in Ethereum currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Into Ethereum (protocol) there is nothing related to zk-SNARKs. But there are some researchs and applications trying to propose it.

The most notable may be ZoKrates, which is also available as plugin (i.e. an external module which can be attached to your application to perform some functions) for the smart contract development environment Remix-IDE platform (you can find it at https://remix.ethereum.org).

The plugin is: Toolbox For ZkSNARKs On Ethereum.

Generally speaking, the problem is the heavy computational effort you must add to your SC. But the ZoKrates effort to make it easily available for developer is significant.

Comment: so in short, so far transaction on Ethereum is not confidential?

Comment: So far, definitively, they are not confidential.

Answer (score 0):

Fully support Rick Park's answer, but just wanted to add that if you wanted a solution you can use now you can try out tornado cash.  It implements zkSnarks to create private transactions.  Read about it here: https://github.com/tornadocash/tornado-core